App installed on a lower minSdk -> Many crashes
I just launched my first Android app and in Crashlytics I see errors which are I think related due to the fact the user has a lower Android version than my app supports.
This is my build.gradle.kts:
android {
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 31
        targetSdk = 34
    }
}

I can also verify the minSdk in Play Store:

And I see this in Crashlytics (Android version 11 = sdk 30 which is lower than the minSDK):

If I try to spin up an emulator with Android version 11 I get an error that the SDK is too low. How did somebody installed the app?

You can sometimes force install an application if you so choose to. The OS warns you about this and lets you do it. SO Question.
